# Why does sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass appear in the stack

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, classloading

I have instrumented JDK and application. Entry and exit points are recorded for call graph construction.

The call graph looks like

> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass->com.example.Main.main
>   ->sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass->com.example.Foo.foo

Source code

```
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args){
  Foo.foo()
}
}

public class Foo{
  public static void foo(){};
}
```

This must be how classloader works but I don't see anything shows in bytecode that indicate the call site "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass". So, how does classloader work internally?

Comment: This is called the first time a class is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are loaded lazily.

You can see this by writing code to print to the console within static initialisers.

The first time a class reference is used by any code loaded by a specific class loader, the JVM request the `Class` from the loader in the current thread. If the parent class loader hasn't loaded a class of the fully qualified name, then the current class loader will define it (or throw an exception).

In the early days applets would make a network connection for each class file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain why there is no corresponding method dispatch in bytecode? Is it some method calling mechanisms that I am not aware of?

Comment: Yes, it's the JVM itself that discovers that you're trying to refer to a class that hasn't been loaded yet. It will use the same classloader that loaded the class that refers to the unknown class.

Comment: In this case it'll be the `invokestatic` to `Foo.foo` that causes the `Foo` class to be loaded. But only the first time. After that `Main.main` could be compiled to call the method directly (or inline) without the lookup. In fact I think the interpreter switches the bytecode to an internal one (but don't quote me on that).

Comment: Strangely enough, I can not find any official documents that describe this loading process....

Comment: @Saddy Chapter 5 of the JVM spec is a bit loose. It does say the loadClass is called by the JVM and what happens to exceptions. (Deviations from the Reference Implementation within the spec are likely to cause problems due to real world programmer's use of cyclic dependency and static variables. Though it's mostly the early boot classes that fail. I guess those failing prevent us from finding about any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have a peek at:
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3700054/all-about-java-class-loaders.html
There are at least 3 different classloaders in a JVM - more if you want to use your own.
in a nut shell, the classloader that loaded the class thats wanting a new class, calls its classloader, that in turn calls its classloader etc, if the top level classloader cant find it, it works its way back down the hierarchy.
The above mentioned link gives a nice picture.